# I get ORA-13605 when trying to run SQL Tuning Advisor from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, database-tuning, oracle-sql-developer

When trying to use the SQL Tuning Advisor from SQL Developer I get this error.

Tuning advisor was working some days before.

[image]

Comment: You get this no matter what the SQL? Have you tried a different user?

Comment: I tried this in different VMs and with different users. It works sometimes, but after analyzing some long query I get the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Oracle Support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is very simple. The string of the query is just too long.

I'm trying to optimize a stored procedure using dynamic sql with a parameter to decide if the sql is executed or output.

I just copied the output into a fresh sql developer pane and tried to use the tuning advisor.

The problem is that the generated output has a lot of **trailing blanks**, I just have to remove them.

Comment: How long is too long - are you hitting the [32K limit](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#sthref1550) for Native Dynamic SQL?

Comment: The true sql statement is tuned to be less than 4000 char. It has to run on 10g. But printed to output and coped to a file it got 415 KB due to trailing blanks.

Comment: wow, that is a lot of blanks :) well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch your browser's language settings.

If the database is running with American/America, switch your browser to en-us. Then re-connect and run the task again.

This fixed up our SQL Tuning Advisor task which failed with the same error.